# Percentage change in velocity

Tags: math, time, geometry, percentage

So, if i have a building that takes 2 days and 4 hours to construct e.g., and i'm going 40% faster than the iniciall time that would have take to build this building, how much time is inicial one, plus, if I'm going 45% faster, how much time would reduce ?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you work constantly without stopping, it takes 52 hours to build  going 40% faster you can simply use a **inverse proportion**, where `140*52=x*100` where x is the time it takes to build at normal speed, which in this case `x=72.8 hours`. To check for other speed just replace the 140 with the new percentage, just remember to add 100 as you are going x% faster plus the initial speed.

Comment: No, I mean, 52 hours (2days + 4 hrs) is the time already with 40% faster